# How can I make a 10-Col grid with bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to put empty element in the first and the last node. 
But what is the proper way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

If you offset it by one `.col-xs-offset-1`, this should give you centered 10 column-wide area to work with.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```